# Select rows except one in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am selecting specific fields in a table for instance ID, NAME, DATE, from a users table but get it to not display one ID because it's an admin ID (which is 11) and I don't want it to be displayed when I am displaying all users. I have tried where ID NOT 11 and various others, but it doesn't do anything.

Here's the MYSQL query:

```
SELECT id, name, DATE FROM users WHERE id != 11 AND DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: How about `SELECT id, name, DATE FROM users WHERE id <> 11`? The date clause doesn't make that much sense, only in the case you are updating it frequently (i.e. when logging) and want to see who has logged in on that day. And I would never trust numeric IDs, filter based on user role assignments instead of some ID value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to display all rows in `users` where `id` is not `11` and `date` is today (that's what I infer from your query). If I'm correct, the right way to do it would be:

```
select id, name, `date`
from users
where id <> 11 -- or "not (id = 11)"
  and `date` = date(now());
```

Notice that I'm enclosing the `date` column between back-ticks (`) to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: It does work! I am so silly, I was putting the id <> 11 or != 11 in the wrong query and whenever I refreshed, it didn't update because I was running the wrong query! haha, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @uhiuehwuiw Happy to help. By the way, if you find this question useful, please up-vote it and/or accept it.

Comment: @uhiuehwuiw One more thing: Your query also didn't work because you were not making a comparisson with the date, you were merely evaluating `DATE(NOW())`, which will give you the date of today.

Comment: I would up-vote it if I had enough reputation, but I'll accept it no problem.